# Put and Use .properties file outside Jar

Tags: java, netbeans, properties, jar

I'm developing a Java Application in Netbeans. The application uses a **.properties** file (`Properties` class). The problem is that Netbeans insert this properties file into final .jar file.

1. How can I make Netbeans not to do this and put the properties file out of jar file?
2. In this case, how can I use the properties file in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the source directories that NetBeans is asked to insert into the JAR and remove the `.properties` from the list.

You can always read the `.properties` file by reading it as an `InputStream`, as long as it's in the `CLASSPATH`.

The question is: Why do you feel the need to move it out of that JAR?  At least it's in the CLASSPATH that way.  You seem to be acting against your own best interests here.

Comment: thank for your answer :) I have two problem with properties file inside Jar. First, I need to __change__ the properties file a lot and I don't know how should I change a file inside jar! I know it's just a package but editing a file inside it is painful. Second, I have other apps which use the very same properties file and I need to keep all of the versions in sync. It is much easier if it exists outside jar.

Comment: I think this is likely to be a very bad design indeed.  If you're changing them a lot, I'd recommend a database.

Comment: I seriously dislike this attitude. You don't know the requirements, you don't know the constraints. still very quick to object to the question itself. When you are done answering, your job is over. you will get points for that,

Comment: Funny, the guy who asked the question liked it well enough to accept it three years ago. You're entitled to your opinion, but I need no instruction from you.

Answer (score 1):

when you export project by jar formart from Eclipse IDE, you can config it do not import file .properties into jar file.

If you want use .properties file in the same folder with file jar, you can get current path with code:

```
String path = <NameClass>.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

and now, you can load file .properties from above path.

Good luck to you!

Comment: Sorry!!! I think most of Java developer is using Eclipse IDE. I can't not support for NetBean IDE.

Comment: Nope, lots of Java developers using IntelliJ.  I think it's better than both Eclipse and NetBeans.